# Ajax function not being hit in submitHandler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Form validation works, but I can't get the Ajax call to fire correctly. The `submitHandler` is being reached, but the Ajax call isn't. I have included a Fiddle at the bottom, but obviously you can't fire ajax calls from there.

```
    $(".player-code, .submit").hide();

//VALIDATION
$(function () {
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            playerClass: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function () {
            var accountNumber = $(".accountNumber").val();
            var domain = $(".domain").val();
            var playerClass = $(".playerClass").val();
            var dataString = accountNumber + playerClass;
            //Save Form Data........
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: dataString,
                success: function () {
                    $(".player-code").show();
                    $('.render-info').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>You've successfully built your player code</div>");

                },
                failure: function () {
                    $('.render-info').html("<div class='alert alert-failure'>Submission Error</div>");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod("domainChk", function (value, element, params) {
    if (this.optional(element)) return true;
    var regExp = new RegExp("^(?!www\\.|http:\/\/www\.)(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\\.)+([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$");
    return regExp.test(value);
}, "Valid hostname required for player code");

jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
    domainChk: {
        domainChk: true
    }
});

$('input[type="text"]').on('click keyup blur', function () {
    if ($('#form').valid()) {
        $(".submit").show();
    } else {
        $(".submit").hide();
    }
});

//PREPOPULATE ACCOUNT FROM QUERY STRING
var url = window.location.href; 
var regex = /=.*/; // match '=' and capture everything that follows
var accountId = url.match(regex);
    $(".accountNumber").val(accountId).remove("=");
//
```

jsFiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/e04rca0t/10/)

Comment: There is no `failure:` option for `$.ajax()`.  Perhaps you meant to use `error:`.

Comment: There is error in your fiddle `$(".accountNumber").val(accountId).remove("=");`

Comment: @DmitryMasley, accidentally included in fiddle.

Comment: Is your question just wrong when you say:  "The `submitHandler` is being reached" because the answer you accepted makes it sound like the submitHandler was NOT being reached.

Comment: I got the solution from the comments above and answers below. The question was phrased correctly. I was able to alert out a message right after the submitHandler, but the ajax function wasn't being hit because I had `failure` instead of `error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `failure:` option for `$.ajax()`.  If you want to see any errors that happen in the ajax call, then use `error:` to capture the error.

Answer (score 0):

To make form submit you should use

`<button class="btn btn-default submit" type="submit">Submit</button>`

instead of `<div class="btn btn-default submit">Submit</div>`

`submitHandler` will be called only on native form submit.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e04rca0t/11/)

Comment: But the OP said "The `submitHandler` is being reached", so I'm confused about how this fixed the problem.

Comment: I added `console.log()` to `submitHandler` and got nothing in fiddle. So appears in this version it was not reached.

Comment: @jfriend00, the button was not completely correctly set as Dmitry did. If you can supply your answer as an actual answer, and not a comment, I will choose it as the correct answer.